# Get id in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, attr

I have a strange problem. I have used this before with no problems, but all of a sudden it doesn't work at all. I'm trying to get the id value of an element:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").live('click', function(event) {               
            var name = $(this).text();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var id = this.id;
            alert(id);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the element:

```
<img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/test.jpg" id="myId"/>
```

I have tried the alert with both the variants above, with this.id directly and via the attr function. Neither works. $(this).text() works fine.

I get "undefined" in the alert box...

What is going on?

Comment: A quick test works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LvyfD/ . In general, however, you shouldn't re-declare variables (`var id` is there twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from this example your code works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/VwzZm/ so the error must be elsewhere.

In fact text() does this:

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants.

And so it's very unlikely that it gets your id.

Comment: Actually, it was a very simple mistake, I had changed the view to a test page and forgot about it, so I was adding the id on the wrong view. So I would say this answer is the closest in identifying that. Sorry to all!

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the id with

```
var id = this.id;
```

again after fetching it

Comment: this is not a problem because you get the id anyway

Answer (score 0):

Remove the row `var id = this.id;` and the script should work.